# Nested Relations include in Sequelize with node js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Models `Price`, `Varient One` ,`Varient Two` ,`Item` 
One Item have varient one and varient two , and many prices

They are my relations

```
db.tbl_itemPrice.belongsTo(db.tbl_varientOne,{foreignKey:'varientOne'})
db.tbl_itemPrice.belongsTo(db.tbl_varientTwo,{foreignKey:'varientTwo'})
db.tbl_item.hasMany(db.tbl_price,{foreignKey:'item'})
```

And then I want to join the table item , price, varient one and varient two .
This is my controller-

```
exports.find = (req, res) => {
    Price.findAll ({
        include:[{
            model:VarientOne,VarientTwo

        }],

    }).then (item => {
        res.send(item)
    });
};
```

How can I join all above tables in sequelize

Answer (score 1):

It is same as what you did.

```
include:[
    {model:A},
    {model:B},
    {model:C,include:[{model:C.1}]},
    {model:D,include:[{model:D.1,include:[{model:D.1.2}]}]},
]
```